# No access to python server

Tags: server, python

I got a local python server up and running on an ubuntu machine. In my ubuntu machine i ran the command to start it:

`python3 -m http.server`

Here is the response i got in the terminal: **Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/)...**

I then, try to download a file using my 2nd ubuntu machine that is on the same network using this command:

`wget 0.0.0.0/name-of-the-file`

And i get this error: **Connecting to 0.0.0.0:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
ERROR 404: Not Found.**

But if i run the same command in the 1st ubuntu machine, it works. So i don't think the path is wrong. I even tried to open the link http://0.0.0.0/name-of-the-file in a web browser and it works. I turned off the firewall and it still doesn't work. Any ideas what might stop pc2 to connect with pc1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.0.0.0 isn't a valid destination address. It essentially means "this host on this network" (which is why it "works" when you use it from the same machine where the web server is running).

To connect from a different host in your local network, you will need to use the IP address of the server interface that's connected to your LAN. You will also need to specify the listening port: something like `192.168.1.4:8000`

If you don't know what the IP address is, you can use something like `ip addr show` to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it worked !